# Excel creates new sheet from invisible data in pivot table cell

Tags: excel-2010, datasource, pivot-table

I have been sent a pivot table in excel 2010, and the data in the cell is linked to data not visible on any of the sheets when double clicked. When the cell is clicked on a new sheet is created with data not previously visible on any sheet. However, when I use the pivot table tools to search for the data source it leads me to data in one of the visible sheets and does not allow me to click on the external data source section. I would like to create something like this/ understand how the cells are simultaneously linked, as I do not understand which data is most relevant to the cell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site serves to answer specific questions about specific programming issues. You may get some helpful comments here, but to get an actual answer, you'll have to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you have selected a [calculated field](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/01/27/pivot-table-tricks/) (select your PT, PivotTable Tools > Options > Tools - Formulas, List Formulas). In other words, you *are* able to see the relevant source data in your spreadsheet but you are not *recognising* it as it does not look familiar to you because a formula in the PT has combined or modified this data.

Note, above based on Excel 2007 however.